# Trouble finding out why the page is rendering differently

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, sanity

I was trying to implement Sanity IO and was messing with a bunch of files and making new files and so on. Then poof my local host:3000 went from looking sleek and fancy to just having a white back ground. It almost looks like a web page from the 90s or something. Attached is my original background that is right and then after. I think I may have screwed up Tailwind some how but the files seem to be there. Anyways I was wondering if anyone would be able to tell just by the description and pic of this.

Before [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayc6Y.png
After [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti3k9.png

Comment: Looks like broken css file?